# Как сделать проверку на подключение к интернету и вывести на экран ответ?

Tags: android

Как сделать проверку на подключение к интернету и вывести на экран ответ?
Пробовал это, но оно не работает:

````
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Работает", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Не работает", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    }```
````

Comment: Раскройте подробнее что значит "не работает"? Вообще, задача в принципе нерешаемая. Даже если получить наличие реального соединения с интернетом, а не с к-л сетью, в которой интернет может быть или не быть (это как раз про ваш код), то, к моменту, когда произойдёт отображение этой информации, интернет может уже пропасть. Обратное тоже верно. Скорее всего вам не нужно решать такую задачу. А вот какую нужно - из вопроса не ясно.

Comment: Под словом (не работает) имею в виду что не показывает Toast

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasConnection(final Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

И в манифест добавьте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Добавил Toast и оно не показывается
```if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }```

Comment: Во все if условия добавьте

Comment: Я во все 3 добавил